# RSA Decryption across Android - iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, objective-c, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to implement a system where A generates an RSA key pair and sends the public key to B.  B then generates an AES key and encrypts it using the public key, sending the result back to A.  A then decrypts the AES key using its RSA private key, encrypts the data using the AES key and send it to B, who can then decrypt it using the AES key.

I've got this all working on the Android side, but I can't get the iPhone side to play ball (I'm new to Objective C so that's probably why!)

Initially, I was getting an error 9809 when decrypting the AES key using the RSA private key, which unhelpfully translates to a general error.  Researching the error points to the padding (I'm using PKCS1 Padding) being the problem, switching to No Padding allowed the iPhone client to decrypt successfully, but the decrypted AES key is different from the one generated on the Android client.

Objective C is very new to me and I'm sure I'm just making a schoolboy error, can anyone point me in the right direction please?

**iPhone RSA key pair generation**

```
static const unsigned char _encodedRSAEncryptionOID[15] = {

    /* Sequence of length 0xd made up of OID followed by NULL */
    0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86,
    0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00

};

NSData * publicTag = [publicKeyIdentifier dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Now lets extract the public key - build query to get bits
NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id) kSecClassKey
                   forKey:(__bridge id) kSecClass];
[queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag
                   forKey:(__bridge id) kSecAttrApplicationTag];
[queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA
                   forKey:(__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyType];
[queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                   forKey:(__bridge id) kSecReturnData];

CFTypeRef pk;
OSStatus err = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, &pk);

NSData* publicKeyBits = (__bridge_transfer NSData*)pk;

if (err != noErr) {
    return nil;
}

// OK - that gives us the "BITSTRING component of a full DER
// encoded RSA public key - we now need to build the rest

unsigned char builder[15];
NSMutableData * encKey = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
int bitstringEncLength;

// When we get to the bitstring - how will we encode it?
if  ([publicKeyBits length ] + 1  < 128 )
    bitstringEncLength = 1 ;
else
    bitstringEncLength = (([publicKeyBits length ] +1 ) / 256 ) + 2 ;

// Overall we have a sequence of a certain length
builder[0] = 0x30;    // ASN.1 encoding representing a SEQUENCE
// Build up overall size made up of -
// size of OID + size of bitstring encoding + size of actual key
size_t i = sizeof(_encodedRSAEncryptionOID) + 2 + bitstringEncLength +
[publicKeyBits length];
size_t j = encodeLength(&builder[1], i);
[encKey appendBytes:builder length:j +1];

// First part of the sequence is the OID
[encKey appendBytes:_encodedRSAEncryptionOID
             length:sizeof(_encodedRSAEncryptionOID)];

// Now add the bitstring
builder[0] = 0x03;
j = encodeLength(&builder[1], [publicKeyBits length] + 1);
builder[j+1] = 0x00;
[encKey appendBytes:builder length:j + 2];

// Now the actual key
[encKey appendData:publicKeyBits];

// Now translate the result to a Base64 string
Base64* base64 = [[Base64 alloc] init];
NSString* ret = [base64 encode:encKey];

return ret;
```

**Re-creating the public key, generating the AES key and encrypting it on Android**
(note the `getBytes(...)` and `getString(...)` just do some base64 encoding.decoding)

```
KeyGenerator keyGen  = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGen.init(256, new SecureRandom());
SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();

byte[] publicKeyBytes = getBytes(publicKey.getKey());
PublicKey rsaKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    .generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes));

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rsaKey);

String keyEncoded = getString(key);

return getString(encryptedKeyBytes));
```

**Decrypting the AES key on iPhone**

```
Base64* base64 = [[Base64 alloc] init];
NSData* cipherText = [base64 decode:textBase64];

const uint8_t *cipherBuffer = (const uint8_t*)[cipherText bytes];

size_t cipherBufferSize = strlen((char *) cipherBuffer);

uint8_t *plainBuffer = (uint8_t *)calloc(SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey), sizeof(uint8_t));
size_t plainBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);

OSStatus status = SecKeyDecrypt(privateKey,
                       kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                       &cipherBuffer[0],
                       cipherBufferSize,
                       &plainBuffer[0],
                       &plainBufferSize
                       );

NSData* finalData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:plainBuffer length:plainBufferSize];
NSString *result = [base64 encode:finalData];

return result;
```

EDIT: I think I've narrowed this down a bit, the following code from the Decrypting the AES key part of my code:

```
NSData* cipherText = [base64 decode:text];
NSLog(@"cipherText %@", cipherText);
const uint8_t *cipherBuffer = (const uint8_t*)[cipherText bytes];
NSLog(@"cipherBuffer %s", cipherBuffer);

size_t cipherBufferSize = strlen((char *) cipherBuffer);
NSLog(@"cipherBufferSize %zd", cipherBufferSize);
```

Produces the following output in the console:

```
cipherText <31226275 cc56069a e96b7f6f 0fbee853 32d07de6 436755c9 e27b88a6 04176947     d57f7108 de68e5b8 49595e9f 09bceb30 1d615927 c205f205 eb644fa7 bff6c02b 885605de eb5bd4ee 473bb4d3 df768017 24552706 ea67f347 2952614e ad63f3c6 eb0022d3 a0513afa 0e59ba63 cb5c9787 a40ecad4 a866fdc7 26b60cc2 088a3499 a84c0595 fb1c2be8 5c85b88d 7856b4bd 655f6fec 905ca221 d6bb03c0 7329410b b235ef8f 1ef97a64 7fabb280 90118ff7 4b1e91f6 162134fc 5cbf962e 813e39e7 993b0fb9 e3c4b30c ef6a7b90 9d64c41a 1211ab34 c2c52235 d2ec3b65 d1314cee 70eafe65 f4a6c5e4 660cf889 4540a784 d14cc5a8 49a12c43 c76f7f03 5fbcd44f>
cipherBuffer 1"buÃVöÈkoæËS2–}ÊCgU…‚{à¶iG’qﬁhÂ∏IY^ü  ºÎ0aY'¬ÚÎdOßøˆ¿+àVﬁÎ[‘ÓG;¥”ﬂvÄ$U'ÍgÛG)RaN≠cÛ∆Î
cipherBufferSize 97
```

Occasionally however, it comes out with a cipher buffer size of 256 as expected and the decryption works perfectly! I know I must be missing something obvious?

Comment: *B then generates an AES key and encrypts it using the public key, sending the result back to A* > Side note - have you considered having B sign the data before encryption? How does A know the key came from B?

Comment: I don't know anything about the iPhone but I'm skeptical about some of your statements. What does "I've got this all working on the Android side" mean? Simply encrypting without generating an error doesn't mean it is working. Can you also correctly decrypt on the Android side? Also, by removing the padding requirement on the iPhone side you've eliminated the only mechanism the iPhone has of detecting a problem. It doesn't return an error because it has no way of detecting an error. It is still possible that anything and everything is incorrect. Leave the PKCS1 padding option on.

Comment: The fact that removing padding produces a decrypted key thats wrong suggests that your on the money here.  I just don't even know where to start with working out whats wrong!  By "all working on the Android side" I mean that I can perform the whole process correctly between two Android devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the `strlen` function, which does not work on binary data in general, it only works on binary data that represents text and it concluded with a zero valued byte (`\0`). Instead you should use the actual size of the ciphertext.

So currently your code block will fail if the ciphertext contains a zero valued byte, or if it is not directly followed by a zero valued byte.